# Control iMac and LED Cinema Display Brightness Simultaneously

Tags: imac, cinema-display, display

I have a iMac 27'' and a LED Cinema Display 27'' connected to it. And I've noticed that to be able to control brightness I need to open the `Display.prefPanel`  and modify the brightness of the displays **individualy**.

Is there a way to do this **simultaneously**? Maybe with a third party app? If not, is there a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to the second display brightness?

Comment: How do you control Cinema Display brightness? My Display.prefPanel only have main screen brightness control.

Comment: Try <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd> and <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>. That should work.

Answer (score 2):

I just started using [Dimmer Than Dim](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dimmer-than-dim/id418816854?mt=12), a free app in the App Store. I only have one display (iMac), however.

Answer (score 1):

[F.lux](http://lifehacker.com/5158832/flux-changes-your-screen-brightness-by-time-of-day) is worth a look, it changes the colour temperature and brightness of your monitor(s) based on the time of day.

Comment: Sadly F.lux is totally automatic and it really doesn't even change the display brightness.

Answer (score 0):

[Shades](http://www.charcoaldesign.co.uk/shades) can do this.

(I am pretty sure it can, I only have one monitor attached at the moment, so I can't verify.)

Comment: In my testing, Shades can control both individually but not simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

**[Lunar](https://lunar.fyi/)** has [Sync Mode](https://lunar.fyi/#sync) which automatically detects changes in brightness on your iMac screen (even those made by the light sensor) and syncs them automatically to the LED Cinema display.

It doesn't use a software overlay. In fact, Apple vendored displays get special treatment as Lunar uses an implementation hidden inside macOS Display Services to control them natively.

*Note that you have to connect the USB port of the LED Cinema to the iMac to enable the DisplayServices method of changing brightness to work.*

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of Lunar